# 2160p ultra wide monitors

Tags: monitors

Am I missing something, or does there not appear to be any 2160p ultra wide monitors?

LG did the [34WK95U](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-34WK95U-W-ultrawide-monitor), but that appears to have been discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick search I've also found the

Dell UltraSharp U4021QW and the MSI Prestige PS341WU